# Grouping routes by domain but WWW doesn't work?

Tags: php, laravel

Take this for example

```
Route::group(['domain' => 'something.net', 'middleware' => 'frontend', 'namespace' => 'Frontend'], function() {
```

When visiting something.net it works perfectly, but when visiting 'www.something.net' it returns a page not found 404 error.

Can anyone work out why, surely they both count as the same domain?

Comment: Please define what does and does not work and how the output/results differ

Comment: The www. does't hit the route group, I thought that was obvious? It returns the page not found 404 page.

Comment: `example.com` and `www.example.com` aren't the same addresses and I think Laravel actually are looking at the complete host name (otherwise it wouldn't be able to handle sub domains). Here's a discussion about it on laracast: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/routing-for-optional-subdomain-domain-and-optional-tld?page=1

Comment: Adding info from the ops response to a question